# Need a Facebook Strategy

Tags: facebook, social-media

I run a website / webapp. It's a mix of regularly updated content, and some subscribers only features. Here's what I have done so far for social distribution:

- **Google Groups** - Set up private and semi private Google Groups of email based distribution.
- **Twitter Updates** - I have successfully synced Twitter with my RSS feed to distribute updates real-time to followers. Included "Follow on Twitter" links on the website.
- **"Tweet"** - Included the Tweet button on content pages.
- **"Recommend on Facebook"** - Included the Recommend on Facebook button on content pages.

I'm not satisfied with my Facebook strategy tho. Is there more I can do? How do I get "followers" and real-time sync content on FB? I don't want to mix them up with my personal friends. With Twitter, this was so easy.

Looking for ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For content intergation check out:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

Facebook does not require you to use your personal account... **Check out this article:**

- [Facebook Group vs Facebook Fan Page: What’s Better?](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/facebook-group-vs-facebook-fan-page-whats-better/7761/)

Also, you might want to look into http://hootsuite.com for social media campaign management.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i write a blog post i post a twitter update.  Then twitter automatically places an update on my facebook fan page.

My twitter strategy includes following a lot of people.  The facebook strategy gives our users a discount on membership if they are a fan or recommend, or a FREE 14 day trial for a tweet.

Try to build incentives to get people to aggregrate your content.
Another thing to keep in mind is to produce your content for video format, then post it up on Vimeo and Youtube.  This is important as YouTube is becomming a search engine.

Last, make sure your site is seo friendly, down to making sure you show up for image searches for key phrases.  about .05% of our searches come from google image search.

Its an all hands on deck approach.

You can also try services such as wildfireapp to get your facebook fans up.